# Need help on php required

Tags: php, function

It may sound like a dumb question but i am confused right now of rand() function on how to have it inside a text box below is my code

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html> 
    <body>

    <?php

         print"<input type='text' name='name'echo(rand()' disabled>"

             ?>
         </body>
               </html>
```

That code isnt working ? So how can i make it work ,Please Help

Comment: Should be `print"<input type='text' name='name' value='".rand()."' disabled>";`

Comment: print"<input type='text' name='name' value=".rand()." disabled>"

Comment: Thanks Alot You All Helped Me

Comment: You could also do `<input type='text' name='name' value='<?php echo rand();?>' disabled>` to keep as much of your HTML outside of PHP tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
     echo "<input type='text' name='name' value='" . rand() . "' disabled>";
?>
```